# Socket.io namespace connection confuse

Tags: websocket, socket.io

All:

I am pretty new to socket.io, when I tried namespace, I wonder why both the default channel and specified channel get called like:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("Send chat page");
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("Connected");
});

var chat = io.of("/chat");
chat.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("Connected chat");
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And the client code is like:

```
  var socket = io("http://localhost:3000/chat");
```

When I run it, the console print out both "Connected" and "Connected chat"

**I wonder why it works like this and how to only connect to chat channel?**

Thanks

Comment: I believe it works that way because that is how they implemented it.  While the documentation is not 100% clear, it does give the impression that there will always be a default connection, and that is how it operates.  If you only want to connect to one channel, just don't attach any listeners to io.on...

Comment: @Gary Thanks, so socket.io connection works more like level by level? First connect the default /,  then connect any namespace_level2 under /, then any namespace_level3 under namespace_level2  ?

Comment: I know it works as / (default), and /namespace (namespace).  I doubt that you can have multiple levels, but give it a try.  My understanding is that if you use namespace, you get a default channel, and one namespace.